# VBA: Move multiple elements at once in userform

Tags: vba, excel, userform

I want to expand my userform when i click on a Checkbox. Some elements should move by the same value that my userform expands so that they always keep the same distance from the bottom border of the form.

At the moment i move every element individually like so where "Ausklapphoehe" is the value for moving/expanding (it's working perfectly but ist not nicely coded i think):

```
Private Sub Filtereigenschaften_Click()
    If Filtereigenschaften.Value = False Then                       
        Filtergruppe.Visible = False

        UserForm.Height = UserForm.Height - Ausklapphoehe
        Button.Top = Button.Top - Ausklapphoehe
        FHLabel.Top = FHLabel.Top - Ausklapphoehe
        FHBox.Top = FHBox.Top - Ausklapphoehe
        NutenabstandLabel.Top = NutenabstandLabel.Top - Ausklapphoehe
        NutenabstandBox.Top = NutenabstandBox.Top - Ausklapphoehe
        SpinButton.Top = SpinButton.Top - Ausklapphoehe
        VersionLabel.Top = VersionLabel.Top - Ausklapphoehe
    End If
    If Filtereigenschaften.Value = True Then                        
        Filtergruppe.Visible = True

        UserForm.Height = UserForm.Height + Ausklapphoehe
        Button.Top = Button.Top + Ausklapphoehe
        FHLabel.Top = FHLabel.Top + Ausklapphoehe
        FHBox.Top = FHBox.Top + Ausklapphoehe
        NutenabstandLabel.Top = NutenabstandLabel.Top + Ausklapphoehe
        NutenabstandBox.Top = NutenabstandBox.Top + Ausklapphoehe
        SpinButton.Top = SpinButton.Top + Ausklapphoehe
        VersionLabel.Top = VersionLabel.Top + Ausklapphoehe
    End If
End Sub
```

I have three ideas to shorten the code:

1. Store the element"IDs" in an Array and perform the repeating Task by iterating over the Array (dont know how to store the elements in an Array)
2. Simply Group the elements and perform Task just to the Group (dont know how to adress Groups in vba code)
3. give the elements a mutual tag and just adress the elements over the tag  (dont know how to adress tags)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use a "**Group**", place a `Frame` to your form and place/drag the controls on it.
When you move the frame, all controls on it move with it. Set the `border` and `caption`-properties of the frame if you want to make the frame itself invisible. If you write something like `Me.Frame1.Visible = false`, it hides also all controls on that frame.

To access controls using **tag**:

```
Sub ControlsByTag(tag As String)
    Dim ctrl As Control
    For Each ctrl In Me.Controls
        Debug.Print ctrl.Name, ctrl.tag
    Next ctrl
End Sub
```

To use **arrays**:

```
' Assign to array:
Dim a
a = Array(Me.CommandButton1, Me.CommandButton2)

' Loop over the array:
Dim i As Long
For i = LBound(a) To UBound(a)
    Debug.Print a(i).Name, a(i).tag
Next i
```

Comment: thanks! didnt know i can hide the border and the caption of a Frame.

Answer (score 2):

There is a `Tag` property of every object, you can assign all the objects you'd like to move a tag like `toBeMoved`. Then the code would be very clear:

```
Private Sub Filtereigenschaften_Click()
    Dim obj As Object
    Dim adj As Variant

    Filtergruppe.Visible = IIf(Filtereigenschaften.Value, True, False)
    adj = IIf(Filtereigenschaften.Value, Ausklapphoehe, -Ausklapphoehe)

    UserForm.Height = UserForm.Height + adj
    For Each obj In Controls
        If obj.Tag = toBeMoved Then obj.Top = obj.Top + adj
    Next obj
End Sub
```

The method for assigning a value into `.Tag` can be written in `UserForm_Initialize()`, or edit it through Properties Window (press F4 if it is hidden) manually.